# Why replacing 2 cables with one did not work?

Tags: electrical

I have recently attempted to move a light switch on one of my walls by extending the cords a bit. At first I attempted to use one wire instead of 2 to save me some work

[image]

and it would not work till I replicated the previous setup with actual 2 wires (simplified pic shown below). Can someone explain to me why?

[image]

Another weird thing here is that the switch took 2 hot wires, which is unusual to me, but I guess it is something I need to lookup instead of asking a double question here.

P.S. I realize one (unrelated to the question) mistake that my initial decision introduced: I decreased the power capacity of that particular place by 50%. Feel free to criticize and whatever. I just want to understand that and to learn.

**Edit:** I don't know the wiring scheme of the house, but if I would swap the hot wires from 2 top cables, it would work, but it would also control 2 other switches on a neighboring wall (i.e. the switch would have to be on for those lights to function ;)

Comment: It's not clear from your diagrams what you changed. The two scenarios are functionally identical. Also, you can't "diminish capacity" with wiring. You either have a circuit or you don't, and the circuit breaker or fuse limits current. I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: The switch doesn't take two hot wires. It merely lets one pass through it (or not, if the switch is off). It seems like you have some fundamental misunderstandings of wiring and electricity and you may be putting yourself and others at risk by doing this work.

Comment: The switch takes **one** hot wire and **one** switched-hot wire.  I mark my switched-hot wires with colored tape (red, orange, brown, whatever will distinguish them from other wire functions in the work area), but that's not code or even necessary, just me doing me.  If you can tell em apart, that's fine.

Comment: @isherwood is right, these two configurations would behave exactly the same way. Which means if one worked and the other didn't, then you didn't actually connect things the way you drew them. Photos would probably be more helpful than drawings at this point. I have a feeling there is more to this than what you've shown in your diagram.

Comment: In the top part of your first picture, one of the 2 wires is incoming from the box and the other goes to a switched light or outlet.  As such, it was either the wiring to your switch, or to the in the 2 nuts in the top of your first pic weren't fully connected, otherwise you would have at least seen power to that switched light / outlet from the top half of your picture.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, everyone. I've appended an edit to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @isherwood, yes, I need to do more reading about wiring and all the switches, recepticles and junction boxes. It's my first project. I just wanted to lift the switch 1.5 ft higher - nothing extraordinary. I have basic understanding about electricity but not very clear, I guess. By decreasing the power capacity I meant that if 2 cables can carry 1440 watts each, joining it in one would make it less capable of delivering that current past it and more chances of tripping or melting.

Comment: Every cable on the circuit should be rated to carry whatever the breaker allows. To invert that statement, the breaker must be rated for only what the weakest link in the circuit can carry. Keep in mind that there's (typically) only one wire connected to a breaker. If that one wire can carry the entire circuit's current there, a similar wire can do so elsewhere in the circuit.

Comment: Your edit tells us that the line voltage coming in is on the **top left cable**. When you reversed the top two cables, you were making all three loads require the switch to be ON to function (passing through the wire nut *after* the switch and splitting three ways). In the current configuration, the line voltage goes to the wire nut first, then on to two always-on circuits (the lower two cables) and one switched circuit (upper right)

Comment: Thanks, @CactusCake. At least it makes more sense what is happening now. And I must have not connected all the wires well the first time.

Comment: @isherwood, I read more last night about house wiring and I do realize that I still have LOTS of gaps in my knowledge. It sounds stupid now, but I sort of envisioned a possibility of those 2 side by side cables being on separate circuits, which (from what I understand) would be a considered a double circuit, if phases matched. Doesn't make sense, I know, hence my confusion about the power capacity.